# accessing SBT settings from scala source

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm wondering if it is possible to read the value of setting key from the main scala sources.

For example, my `build.sbt` contains:

```
name := "hello"

version := "0.1"
```

I want to read the value of `version` and `name` in my scala source files (in `src/main/scala/*.scala`).  Is this possible?

Comment: Not directly. There might be an SBT plugin that will perform substitutions in your sources (certainly there is such a plugin for Maven)

Answer (score 5):

You need sbt-buildinfo (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) plugin for it

```
buildInfoSettings

sourceGenerators in Compile <+= buildInfo

buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](name, version, scalaVersion, sbtVersion)

buildInfoPackage := "hello"
```

it will generate scala file with all properties you need, and you can access them from your scala source

```
package hello

/** This object was generated by sbt-buildinfo. */
case object BuildInfo {
  /** The value is "helloworld". */
  val name = "helloworld"
  /** The value is "0.1-SNAPSHOT". */
  val version = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  /** The value is "2.10.3". */
  val scalaVersion = "2.10.3"

  .....
```